# Thunderbird Questions: Insulator

Tags: science-based, creature-design, low-fantasy

**Introduction:**

I posted a while ago about a lightning dragon and one of the answers was really interesting.  The answer, in this case, is from Mr [Adrian Colomitchi](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/216153/90300), it was very detailed, but I still had doubts with that vocabulary too sophisticated for me to understand, so to reach a greater number of people I decided to make a series of posts about my doubts.

**Question:**

Initially I was planning a dragon, but then I decided to switch to a bird and Mr Adrian's answer gave me one more reason for this change (it said that sharp things like claws, fangs and spinal tips wouldn't work well for intense electrostatic fields).  Then he talked about the skin being made of an insulator to prevent the dragon from suffering damage from the electrical discharge and a part of the insulator being conductive.  However, I changed the creature from scaly to feathered, so I ask, **how would this apply to a bird?**

**Details:**

The bird cannot depend on magic or technology.  I intend to make the bird recharge by flying through the charged clouds, if necessary being the target of electrical discharges until it has enough energy to launch a lightning bolt.  The thunderbird is not a wild species, so it lives with humans as a mount for them, just as horses do. No need to worry about the rider, I already have in mind a way for the rider not to get hurt while riding the bird.  Suggestions for changes to the bird's physiology and the environment in which it lives are welcome.  If the bird's dimensions are relevant, I've found an image that pretty much represents the size I plan it to be:
[image]

Comment: I would suggest that you link to the original question, as this question lacks details that are made reference to.

Comment: a part of the insulator being conductive? What does that mean?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breakdown_voltage

Comment: At least that's what I understood.

Comment: @L.Dutch: the upper level of the skin is perfect insulator. The layer immediately under the skin (the so called [endothelium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endothelium)) must be as conductive as possible - because that's where the charge will be stored on and _from where it will need to leave, at high intensity, once the lightning bolt is triggered_. Any non-trivial electrical resistance from that endothelium and the dragon ends skinless by the explosive evaporation of its endothelium (heating power = R*I^2/2. At _skin/surface_ currents in kA magnitude range... well do I need to continue?).

Comment: @WizardKing The detailed answer that I prepared (and not finished yet) was an attempt on a _reductio ad absurdum_ demonstration on the _impossibility of having it as you asked_ within the context of a `science-based`. See the opening disclaimer of my answer. If you persist in wanting it, you'll have to seriously wander outside the realm of reality and work hard towards a suspension of disbelief.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi, I am not challenging the physics, but the oxymoron of an "insulator being conductive". It's like telling part of the water in the ocean is dry.

Comment: @L.Dutch to be pedantic, dry water can actually exist (in contrast with an insulating conductor), if we're speaking of oceans of water vapors in a supercritical state under the pressure of hundred kilometers thick atmosphere of, say, helium.

Answer (score 1):

Give up on storing charge in your bird without magic, the numbers jost don't work.

maybe instead the bird can deploy a conductive streamer between a charged cloud and the ground causing a preferred path for lightning.

[image: your'e a dirty bird]

We see this effect on power lines (bird streamer flashover), so it can presumably work at larger scales too.

OTOH [Ben Frankiln survived](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kite_experiment), maybe his kite string was too clean.